# Understanding an Inequality on Entanglement Entropy Found in Hastings Paper on the Area Law

Tags: hilbert-space, entropy, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

I am currently reading and trying to reproduce the proof found in the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2024) by Hastings, in which he proves that the ground state of 1D gapped systems follow an area law. On the second page, Hastings begins by setting up a proof by contradiction, saying that suppose there exists a site index $i_0$, such that $S(\rho_{1,i_0}^0) > S_\text{max}$. Here $\rho_{1,i_0}^0$ represents the reduced ground state density matrix on the interval containing sites $1$ to $i_0$ and $S$ is the corresponding entropy. He then states that for all $k > i_0$, the following is true:

\begin{equation*}
S(\rho_{1,k}^0) + (k - i_0)\ln D > S_\text{max} \hspace{0.25in} (1)
\end{equation*}

where $D$ is the dimension of the local Hilbert space at each lattice site. In other words, the local Hilbert space dimension is assumed to the same for all sites throughout the lattice.

**Does (1) suggest $S(\rho_{1,k}^0) + (k - i_0)\ln D = S(\rho_{1,i_0}^0)?$ If so, why is the equality true, mathematically. If not, why is (1) true mathematically?**

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/716578/58382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove inequality (1) using the subadditivity property of entanglement entropy, in particular the Araki-Lieb triangle inequality ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_subadditivity_of_quantum_entropy#Subadditivity_of_entropy); [notes](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Ejrl/teaching/cse599Isp21/notes/lecture9.pdf): Theorem 1.3).

Consider the two non-overlapping set of sites $\{1,...i_0\} , \{i_0+1,...,k\}$ as regions A and B. Then the inequality mentioned above tells us
\begin{align}
S(\rho^0_{1,k}) = S(A\cup B) &\geq |S(A)-S(B)|\\
& \geq S(A)-S(B) \ \ \ \ (\because |x|\geq x \text{ for any real }x) \\
& = S(\rho^0_{1,i_0}) - S(B) \\
& \geq S(\rho^0_{1,i_0}) - \log(D^{k-i_0}) \ \ \ \ (\because S(B) \text{ is bounded above by } \log(D^{k-i_0})) \\
&>S_{max}- \log(D^{k-i_0})
\end{align}

This proves inequality (1).