# Understanding another Inequality on Entanglement Entropy Found in Hastings Paper on the Area Law

Tags: hilbert-space, entropy, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

I am currently reading and trying to reproduce the proof found in the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2024) by Hastings, in which he proves that the ground state of 1D gapped systems follow an area law. I am trying to understand the following inequality found on page 2 of the paper. Here is the text from the paper

> Then, define $S_l$, for each $l ≤ l_0$, to be the maximum entropy of an interval of length $l$ contained in $X_{i,i+l_0}$. That is, $S_l$ is the maximum of $S(ρ^0_{j+1,j+l})$ over j such that $X_{j+1,j+l} ⊆ X_{i,i+l_0}$. Clearly, $S_1 ≤ \ln(D)$. Further, for any $l$, we have $S_{2l} ≤ 2S_l$.

Here $\rho_{j,k}^0$ represents the reduced ground state density matrix on the interval containing sites $j$ to $k$, $S$ is the corresponding entropy, $D$ is the dimension of the local Hilbert space at a site, and $X_{j,k}$ represents the set containing site indices ranging from $j$ to $k$.

**How can I show that $S_{2l} ≤ 2S_l$ is true? Please kindly help.**

Comment: Isn't this just subadditivity of entropy? $S_{l+l}\leq S_l+S_l$?

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə I do not know how to prove that. Can you please kindly tell me  why that inequality is true?

Comment: The inequality used here is known as the subadditivity. The proof can be found in standard texts, e.g. Nielsen and Chuang.

Comment: @MengCheng Thank you very much for the reference!!